# Need to add Column to existing DATAFRAME and assign values based on another column in that data frame using python

Tags: python, dataframe

[image: Column A Maths Science English Social]

i want to add column as newly added column and assign values like where ever maths comes it should be 1,
science it should be 2, english it should be 3, and so on

Finally i want to print that entire dataframe with newly added column

Column A         Newly added column
Maths             1
Science           2
English           3
Social            4
Maths             1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way if you are already using data analysis packages

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

lab = LabelEncoder()

# Encode whole column using Label Encoder:
df['encoded_A'] = lab.fit_transform(df['Column A'])

#It normally starts from 0, so add 1 to new column
df['encoded_A'] = df['encoded_A'] + 1

df
```